# If $p$ is a positive multivariate polynomial, does $1/p$ have polynomial growth?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, inequality, polynomials, asymptotics

I wanted to ask a separate question to focus on an elementary issue from my question [Does the inverse of a polynomial matrix have polynomial growth?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1258614/does-the-inverse-of-a-polynomial-matrix-have-polynomial-growth).

> Let $p : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a polynomial in $n$ real variables, with real coefficients, and suppose that $p > 0$ on all of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
>
> Does $1/p$ have (at most) polynomial growth?  That is, are there constants $C,N$ such that $1/p(\mathbf{x}) \le C (1+|\mathbf{x}|)^N$ for all $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$?

Of course this is true when $n=1$ because in that case we have $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} p(x) = +\infty$, and so $1/p$ is actually bounded.  In higher dimensions this is more subtle: consider for example $p(x,y) = x^2 + (1-xy)^2$ which is strictly positive for all $x,y$, yet $1/p$ is unbounded: consider $p(1/y,y)$ as $y \to \infty$.  For this example, I can use some calculus to show that $1/p(\mathbf{x}) \le 1+\|\mathbf{x}\|^2 \le (1+\|\mathbf{x}\|)^2$, so $1/p$ does have polynomial growth.  But I don't know what to do in general.

Comment: +1 This question kept nagging me since I read the original matrix question a few hours ago

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. By [Stengle's Positivstellensatz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stengle%27s_Positivstellensatz), we can find polynomials $f_1$ and $f_2$, such that each of $f_1$ and $f_2$ can be written as sums of squares of polyomials, and $p f_1 = 1+f_2$. (In Wikipedia's language, take $F = \emptyset$ and $W = \mathbb{R}^n$.) Then $1/p = f_1/(1+f_2) \leq f_1$, which is a polynomial.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like exactly the right thing! I'll plan to accept after I have had a chance to read a little more about the Positivstellensatz.

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble seeing how the statement in the Wikipedia article follows from the statement in Stengle's paper.  Can you offer any hints?

Comment: See Theorem 2.2.1 in https://books.google.com/books?id=Aj5WP_Knu0sC&pg=PA25#v=onepage&q&f=false . (2) is Stengle's Theorem 3, (1) is the statement you want. Skimming the proof, it looks like the order of logic is $(2) \implies (3) \implies (4) \implies (1)$, so it isn't so easy. Someone should probably edit Wikipedia.

Comment: Thanks for making me look this up. I must admit, I've never read the original before now.